# Ajax query when user closes the window?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to execute an ajax query when one user close the window. Ive got this code:

```
var $jQ = jQuery.noConflict();

$jQ(window).bind('unload', function() {

    $jQ.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://www.mydomain.com/post_untrack.php"  ,
       success: function(msg){
          alert("Untrack");
       }
    });

});
```

I receive the "alert" event, but the script is not executed...

post_untrack.php:

```
<?php
mail("myemail@mydomain.com", "Script executed", "Hooray!!!");
?>
```

Any idea ?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work, you need to add the property

```
async: false
```

to `.ajax()` options object, plus you need to execute it on `onbeforeunload` so in jQuery

```
$jQ(window).bind('beforeunload',...);
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, ajax requests are *asynchronous*. So although you may start the request when the window is unloaded, it will probably get cancelled immediately and never actually sent to the user. Although you *could* make the request synchronous, synchronous requests really mess up the user experience by bringing the browser to a screeching halt.

More about this in [this other SO question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970782/javascript-wait-until-ajax-request-finishes-to-close-page).

And of course, any ajax calls will be subject to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

is the URL being posted to on the same domain as the page that is trying to do the ajax call?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: No... im making the ajax call from myotherdomain.com. But I have a previously ajax call to the same domain (but it doesnt trigger when the page is closed) and it works fine.