# Ajax call on onbeforeunload not working in Firefox - works in IE

Tags: .net, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox

I am using the following code which runs fine in Internet Explorer but is not working in Firefox.

When the user closes the browser, a webmethod has to be called, which updates the bit field `IsLogin=false` in the database.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

        var evt = window.event || e;
        var y = evt.clientY || evt.pageY;

        if (y < 0 || evt.clientX<0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Application/WebForm1.aspx/Update",
                async: false,
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert('Sucessfull Call');
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably no reliable way to do this as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970782/javascript-wait-until-ajax-request-finishes-to-close-page

Answer (score 0):

Is your web method getting called at all in FireFox? The [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#changes-2011-05-25) states that calls to alert() may be ignored during the window.onbeforeunload event see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload) for Mozilla's response.

An alternative is to return a confirmation box. This appears to work well in IE/FF/Chrome for me. The document is still visible and the event can be cancelled (if needed).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        var confirmationMessage = "Sucessfull Call";

        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
        return confirmationMessage;
    });
</script>
```